# Is there a meditation on nimitta or animitta?

Tags: meditation

In hindu tradition, is there a meditation technique devoted to nimitta or animitta? Nimitta meaning indication. Animitta means no-indication.

Comment: It is better if you use Hinduism terms for sign and signlessness. Nimitta and animitta are Pali and Buddhism terms as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Sir, It is a sanskrit term. I am not asking about Buddhism. I asking about the prsence of a meditation technique in Hindusim.

Comment: From http://rc.leighb.com/more/Nimitta.htm "The Pali word nimitta literally means "sign."  Nimitta and animitta are Sanskrit words but they don't mean sign and signlessness. They have different meanings. The article I quoted is a Buddhism article. The meaning meditation is taken from Buddhist dictionary.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ok I will edit the question.